# NotifyPropertyChanged pode ou não pode existir nas propriedades publicas de uma Model?

Tags: xamarin, mvvm

Oi, estou criando um App com o padrão MVVM porém algumas questões relacionadas não estou conseguindo esclarecer sobre o assunto, vou deixar o link do App [aqui](https://github.com/lemarcelo/Taskinho) se alguém quiser ver para me apontar algum possível erro ou até mesmo se quiser usar para fins de estudo fique à vontade.

NotifyPropertyChanged **pode** ou **não pode** existir nas propriedades publicas de uma Model?

Se sim, sabe me dizer em que momento ou para qual situação este NotifyPropertyChanged seria utilizado na Model? Pode descrever em situações não necessariamente em código(embora seja melhor).

Valeu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, @MATCH.

Caso esteja se referindo à interface `INotifyPropertyChanged`, este é um contrato para garantir o sincronismo de alteração de dados entre a View e a ViewModel(neste caso não entra o model).

Quando a ViewModel possuí alguma proprieade alterada, este deve invocar o evento `PropertyChangedEventHandler` informando qual proprieade sofreu alteração através do argumento `PropertyChangedEventArgs`

Respondendo a sua dúvida:
NotifyPropertyChanged pode ou não pode existir nas propriedades publicas de uma Model?

A resposta é: Depende, pois sintaticamente você estaria quebrando os princípios do Design Pattern MVVM que diz que somente a ViewModel deve-se comunicar com a View, mas nada te impede de fazer isso, vai funcionar do mesmo jeito, desde que sua ViewModel esteja mapeada para alguma proprieade da Model.

### Classe base para Comum uso entre as ViewModels

```
public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
        /// <summary>
        /// Occurs when a property value changes.
        /// </summary>
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


        /// <summary>
        /// Raises this object's PropertyChanged event.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="propertyName">Name of the property used to notify listeners. 
        /// that support <see cref="CallerMemberNameAttribute"/>.</param>
        protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
        {
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        }
}
```

### Exemplo de Utilização

```
public class MinhaViewModel : BaseViewModel 
{
   private string _minhaString;
   public string MinhaString
   {
     get => _minhaString;
     set
     {
       if(value == _minhaString) return;

       _minhaString = value;
       RaisePropertyChanged()
     }
   }
}
```

Agora `MinhaString` pode ser utilizada na View problemas.

Comment: Entendi Vinicius foi muito claro, obrigado pela resposta e o exemplo.